# Alterando o solver para otimização global no MATLAB

Tags: matemática, matlab, biblioteca, paralelismo, toolbox

Eu tenho um solucionador chamado [SolvOpt](https://imsc.uni-graz.at/kuntsevich/solvopt/index.html) e ele é bom para resolver meu problema de [minimização não suave e sem restrições](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem), mas geralmente ele pára em mínimos locais. No computador da universidade tenho todas as caixas de ferramentas instaladas, mas quero usar algumas boas heurísticas, como o [VNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_neighborhood_search), já implementadas no MATLAB para otimizar globalmente meu problema específico usando o SolvOpt, de preferência em paralelo. Há alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: A sua pergunta está um pouco genérica, você que usar algo para otimizar variaveis? 
 Se sim uma opcão comum é [fmincon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) . Além disso, vc pode dar uma olhada na página do matlab para [otimizacão não linear](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/nonlinear-programming.html). Dê um comentário se é perto disso que você está procurando.

Comment: Então... sim, o Matlab tem essas heuristicas já programadas, mas elas não permitem que eu use o SolvOpt nessas heurísticas, mas somente as que já existem programadas no MATLAB. A ideia de utilizar o SolvOpt dentro de alguma outra heurística é que o SolvOpt é um excelente resolvedor do meu problema em particular e com isso não perco a eficiência do meu método. Imagina se, trocando o Solver, eu comece a obter resultados piores? Seria triste, não?

Comment: Problemas não lineares tem respostas não lineares as vezes :) . Você saber como integrar o SolvOpt no seu codigo então?

Comment: Minha pergunta é para eu, depois de ter  várias abordagens, comparar elas e ver qual é o melhor. Acontece que o meu problema já é bem resolvido com o SolvOpt, então valeria a pena investigar se existe alguma heurística que permite que eu use meu solver internamente nele para que eu consiga aproveitar o máximo do meu solver. Apos isso, eu comparo com as demais heurísticas que o Matlab fornece. Essa etapa de comparar com as já feitas do MATLAB irá acontecer. =) A esperança é que utilizando meu solver as coisas fiquem melhores, pq ele já resolve bem.

Comment: Olá, Guto, sim, já sei. O meu problema já é "resolvido" (teoricamente é possível melhorar, mas na pratica é o melhor que existe até agora) com o SolvOpt, mas é comum acontecer do SolvOpt cair em mínimos locais, justamente por causa que meu modelo tem muitos minimizadores locais.